# How To Change String Resource Xml Values?

Tags: java, android

I need help, How To Change String Resource Xml Values at new value?
I have `<string name="pref_way">/mnt/sdcard/</string>` and change at new value in programming `<string name="pref_way">/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd</string>`

Comment: not possible to modify at run time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify any files in res dynamically during run time. They are read-only.

Instead for this kind of purpose I would recommend you to go for Shared Preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a String resource (or any other type of XML-declared resources) at runtime. Create a String variable in one of you classes that initializes with the resource String and you may change that at your will.